# How can I check several columns for a true or "Y" value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with several columns that need to be checked for either a `TRUE` value or a `"Y"`
What is the simplest way to do this. I checked using an IF function and it worked but was a very long formula. I have attempted to use the `COUNTIF` formula but cannot get it to work.

```
COUNTIF(W2:X2,"Y")+COUNTIF(Z2:AB2,"Y")>0, OR(Y2="TRUE", AC2="TRUE")
```

Here is a link to the spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12k9usKsOgrOUhtW5WBvfY7WB5hbfnTMSPgXtrqcRFjM/edit?usp=sharing

If any `columns A-N` show a `Y` or a `TRUE` i want column `O` to return any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
=IF(OR(countif(A2:N2;"Y");countif(A2:N2;TRUE));"it works";"fail")
```

as the `countif()` returns a number of positive or true cases. Using an `OR()` function to compare the status of both `"Y"` and `TRUE` value counts will return you a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value, which inside the `if()` statement can tell you if ANY of the columns have a `Y`  or `TRUE`, or if ALL of them do not.

#### Fail Case

[image: Fail Case - NO Y or TRUE]

#### "Working" Case

[image: OK Case - 1 or more Y or TRUE]

Answer (score 2):

If you want an array solution (i.e., one that will process all the rows using just one formula), delete everything from Column O in your sample sheet (including the header), and place the following formula in O1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header of Choice";IF(A2:A="",,IF(ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:N)," ",COLUMNS(A1:N1))),"Y|TRUE")),"FAIL","PASS"))})`

You can change the header from within the formula as you like.

The rest of the formula makes use of the fact that the `QUERY` function allows multiple headers (not just 0 or 1). In short, all per-row data is concatenated into `TRANSPOSE`d `QUERY` column headers, then `TRANSPOSE`d back into rows (a cool way to do row-by-row concatenation); then `REGEXEXTRACT` attempts to find "Y" or "TRUE" within each row's concatenated string. If that attempt results in an error, "FAIL" is returned; if it succeeds, "PASS" is returned.

Obviously, you can change "PASS" and "FAIL" to whatever you like.