# How to print different values to column based on value in another column and other conditions met?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with several columns and I want to return a different value based on the value in `Column A` and if any of the other columns show a `true` or `1`.

For example

If `column A` has the value `"A"` and any `column B-N` is either `TRUE` or `1` then I want to return `"Good"` to column `O`

If `column A` has the value `"B"` and any `column B-N` is either `TRUE` or `1` then I want to return `"Best"` to `column O`

Link to spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12k9usKsOgrOUhtW5WBvfY7WB5hbfnTMSPgXtrqcRFjM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, this is basically a duplicate of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67510302/how-can-i-check-several-columns-for-a-true-or-y-value/67510813#67510813). Just do the same thing as you did there, except repeat the `if()` with the condition for `B`. I'll post it as a better explained answer, but you could have saved yourself the time by editing and adding this info on the other question.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure about editing questions after they have been answered. Can I simplify this at all by changing the "Y" or "N" values to 1 and 0?

Comment: I tried something like this but I am not sure how to make it work if I have more than two values in column A    =IF(AND({B2:N2}>0, A2="A"),"Good", "")

Comment: You can. In fact, you can use any terms you'd like, as long as you use them in the formula.  Maybe because you'll be using numbers instead of characters, you can dispose of the quotemarks, but I'm not sure.

Comment: do you need the result to come out in a single cell for the whole sheet, or just one in every row?

Comment: I need one result for every row. I think what I am struggling with is nesting IF statements.

Comment: if you indent the code to separate the statements and the arguments, it gets better to visualize what you are doing. Once the logic seems OK, just turn it to a one-liner and run it. Also, my answer does just that. Use it on yout `O` column, and then use the auto-fill to copy it to every row below as far as you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you already have [this partial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67510302/how-can-i-check-several-columns-for-a-true-or-y-value/67510813#67510813). To get a second condition to be met before printing something to your cell, just add an `AND()` with a new `COUNTIF()`, comparing A column with `A`, and then at the `else` argument, repeat your original `IF()`, just changing `A` for `B` and the output for each case. I will look like this:

```
=IF(AND(countif(A2;"A");OR(countif(A2:N2;"Y");countif(A2:N2;TRUE)));"Good";
IF(AND(countif(A2;"B");OR(countif(A2:N2;"Y");countif(A2:N2;TRUE)));"Best";"BAD"))
```

[image: yay]

To use it on every row, just autofill the column `O`. The row numbers will change accordingly and work on its own.

If you need a new `if()` statement for a third or fourth case, just repeat it, nesting one `IF()` inside the other, leaving room for a default error message at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in cell `O2` (where your sample sheets only has values of `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `Y` or `N` in `B2:N`):

`=arrayformula((trim(transpose(query(transpose(iferror(regexreplace(regexreplace(text(B2:N,),"(FALSE)|(N)",),"(Y)|(TRUE)",if(A2:A="A","Good",if(A2:A="B","Best",))),)),,columns(B2:N))))))`

**Alternative** where values in `B:N` are either `0` or `1`:

`=arrayformula((trim(transpose(query(transpose(iferror(substitute(substitute(B2:N,0,),1,ifs(A2:A="A","Good",A2:A="B","Best")),)),,columns(B2:N))))))`
`B2:N` is the range of cells to process.

The inner `SUBSTITUTE` clears all `0` values.

The outer `SUBSTITUTE` swaps `1` values for a test to see if values in `A` contain `"A"` or `"B"`.

`IFS` does the test and returns either `"Good"` or `"Best"`.

`IFERROR` hides any `#N/A` values down the sheet where the rows are empty.

`TRANSPOSE` transposes the data for `QUERY`.

`QUERY` is used to collapse empty cells (vertically). `columns(B2:N)` is used in the header part of `QUERY`. This is a quirk of `QUERY`, where the header number >= the columns of data, `QUERY` does the collapse.

`TRANSPOSE` reverts the dataset to the previous orientation.

`TRIM` removes leading or trailing space.

`ARRAYFORMULA` allows the formula to automatically cascade down the sheet, rather than you needing to drag the formula down (like with `=IF(AND({B2:N2}>0, A2="A"),"Good", "")`).

Comment: Can i simplify this by changing the Y and N values to 1 or 0? I made that changed in the linked spreadsheet.

Comment: As far as I know, `REGEXREPLACE` expects text and can't replace numbers. That's why `text(B2:N,)` gets your values as text.

Comment: If your values in `B:N` are either `0` or `1`, then the formula is adapted: `=arrayformula((trim(transpose(query(transpose(iferror(substitute(substitute(arrayformula(B2:N),0,),1,ifs(A2:A="A","Good",A2:A="B","Best")),)),,columns(B2:N))))))`